# scala nodes in html-Strings

Tags: scala, jsoup, textnode

my target is to analyze an "html - String". In the end i'd like
to extract the Textnodes and datanodes of a string and store them in 
different lists.

With my first appoach I tried to go through a "html - String" recursively.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import java.util.Iterator
import org.jsoup.nodes
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node

object TextAnalyzer {

    def processNode(node: Node) {
        if (node.isInstanceOf[TextNode]) println(node.toString())
        node.childNodes() foreach processNode
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val myHtml = "<html> <head> <title>Welcome</title>    </head>    <body>        <div>            <p>Foo</p>        </div>    </body></html>";

        val doc = Jsoup.parse(myHtml);
        processNode(doc);

    }
}
```

It ends with the following errow message:

> scalac MyModule.scala

MyModule.scala:23: error: value childs is not a member of org.jsoup.nodes.Node
        node.childNodes() foreach processNode
             ^
one error found
>

Can you get me startet in order to be able to
get the data- and textnodes of a textstring ?
... recursively ?

Thanks in advance for help?

greets

Ansgar

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question - but the following compiles. Is it what you were aiming for?

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import java.util.Iterator
import org.jsoup.nodes._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

    object TextAnalyzer extends App {

        def processNode(node: Node) {
            if (node.isInstanceOf[TextNode]) println(node.toString())
            node.childNodes() foreach processNode
        }

        val myHtml = "<html> <head> <title>Welcome</title>    </head>    <body>        <div>            <p>Foo</p>        </div>    </body></html>";

        val doc = Jsoup.parse(myHtml);
        processNode(doc);

    }
```

Comment: Hi selig! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! I think I should concentrate on some good how tos, including the right objects to inherit (recommendations?)... Cheers and have nice time!